# How do you read from a memory buffer c++

Tags: c++, memory, buffer

I am fairly new at C++ and am trying to understand how memory manipulation works. I am used to Java and Python and haven't really been exposed to this.

I am working on a project that has the following structure that doesn't quite make sense to me.

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t size;
  char *data;
} data_buffer;
```

This structure basically acts as a buffer, with a pointer to the data stored within the buffer and the size of the buffer to allow the program to know how large the buffer is when reading from it.

An example of how the program uses the buffer:

```
data_buffer buffer = {0};
//Manipulate data here so it contains pertinent information
CFile oFile;
oFile.Write(buffer.data, buffer.size);
```

The program mostly uses 3rd party code to read the data found within the buffer, so I am having trouble finding an example of how this is done. My main question is **how do I read the contents of the buffer, given only a pointer to a character and a size?** However, I would also like to understand how this actually works. From what I understand, memory is written to, with a pointer to where it starts and the size of the memory, so I should be able to just iterate through the memory locations, grabbing each character from memory and tagging it onto whatever structure I choose to use, like a CString or a string. Yet, I don't understand how to iterate through memory. Can someone help me understand this better? Thanks.

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of naked arrays, pointers, and `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I'm working on pretty old code, so many things that are already written I can't just redo. I'm just trying to understand how this is actually functioning as a buffer.

Comment: Its not a buffer, it's a buffer handle, carying the address and the size of the actual buffer. And btw. this is more C code than C++ code (Actually a mixture of C and MFC code)

Comment: Use `[]` to access the elements of the buffer like: `char c = buffer.data[5];`.

Comment: for (size_t i=0; i<data_buffer.size; ++i) data_buffer.data[i] gives access to individual characters in buffer. If you want to print the whole string cout << data_buffer.data << endl; should show whats there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers. I understand this so much better now and was able to learn multiple ways to access and potentially manipulate the data found within the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason you cannot use a std::string or CString to manipulate that data. (Use higher level constructs when they are available to you.)

To **get the data into a std::string**, use the constructor or assignment operator:

```
std::string s( buffer.data, buffer.size );
```

You can even stick it in a std::stringstream so you can treat the data buffer like a file:

```
std::istringstream ss( s );

int n;
ss >> n;
```

Things work similarly for the MFC string class.

To **get the data from a string**, you'll need to copy it over. Ideally, you'll be able to allocate the data's memory. Assuming you have data written into a stringstream

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << name << "," << employee_number;
```

You can then allocate the space you need using the function that creates the data_buffer object:

```
function_that_creates_a_data_buffer( buffer, ss.str().size() );
```

If there is no such function (there ought to be!) you must malloc() or new it yourself, as appropriate:

```
buffer.size = ss.str().size();
buffer.data = (char*)malloc( buffer.size );
```

Now just copy it:

```
ss.str().copy( buffer.data, buffer.size );
```

If your buffer needs a null-terminator (I have so far assumed it doesn't), make sure to add one to the size you allocate and set the last character to zero.

```
buffer.size = ss.str().size + 1;
buffer.data = new char[ buffer.size ];
ss.str().copy( buffer.data, buffer.size );
buffer.data[ buffer.size-1 ] = 0;
```

Make sure to look at the documentation for the various classes you will use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are keywords related to buffers: head, tail, init, last, first... depending on how you read / write it.

Answer (score 0):

They are using a `char` array so that you can access each byte of the data buffer since size of `char` is usually 1 byte.

Reading the contents of the data buffer depends on the application. If you know how the internal data is encoded, you can write an unpacking function which selects chunks of the char array and convert/typecast it to the target variables.

eg: Lets say the data buffer is actually a list of integers of size 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  //how the data buffer was probably filled
  int *a = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    a[i] = i;
  }
  char *data = (char *)a;

  //how we could read from the data buffer
  int *b = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
  char *p = data;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    b[i]=(int )*p;
    printf("got value %d\n",b[i]);
    p += sizeof(int);
  }
  free(a);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Note: That being said, since this is C++, it would be much safer if we could avoid using `char` pointers and work with `strings` or `vectors`. Other answers have explored other options of how to handle such buffers properly in C++.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of type char* is actually a pointer to memory. Your struct contains data which is of type char* so it is a pointer to memory. (I suggest writing char* data instead of char *data, to help keep this clear.)

So you can use it as a starting point to look at your data. You can use another pointer to walk over the buffer.

```
char* bufferInspectorPointer;
bufferInspectorPointer = buffer.data;
```

bufferInspectorPointer will now point to the first byte of the buffer's data and

```
*bufferInsepectorPointer
```

will return the contents of the byte.

```
bufferInspectorPointer++
```

will advance the pointer to the next byte in the buffer.

You can do arithmetic with pointers in C++, so

```
bufferInspectorPointer - buffer.data
```

will tell you how many bytes you have covered. You can compare it to buffer.size to see how far you have left to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as C++ I'd recommend using algorithms.  You can get your `iterators` by using `buffer.data` as start and `buffer.data + buffer.size` as end.  So to copy the memory into a `std::string` you'd do something like so:

```
std::string str(buffer.data, buffer.data + buffer.size);
```

Or perhaps to append onto a string:

```
str.reserve(str.size() + buffer.size);
std::copy(buffer.data, buffer.data + buffer.size, std::back_inserter(str));
```

Of course you can always chose a different end so long as it's not past `buffer.data + buffer.size`.